# CMake confusion: Including two subdirectories and calling one from another

Tags: c++, cmake, android-ndk

This is my main CMakeLists.txt

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.10.2)

# Declares and names the project.

project("tunersa")


SET(APP_SOURCES
        tunersa.cpp
        jni_bidge.cpp
        LatencyTuningCallback.cpp
        )

add_library( # Sets the name of the library.
        tunersa

        # Sets the library as a shared library.
        SHARED

        # Provides a relative path to your source file(s).
        ${APP_SOURCES})

add_subdirectory(HelloOboeEngine)
add_subdirectory(SoundGenerator)


find_library( # Sets the name of the path variable.
        log-lib

        # Specifies the name of the NDK library that
        # you want CMake to locate.
        log)

find_package(oboe REQUIRED CONFIG)



target_link_libraries( # Specifies the target library.
        tunersa

        # Links the target library to the log library
        # included in the NDK.
        ${log-lib}
        oboe::oboe
        HelloOboeEngine
        SoundGenerator)

include_directories(${PROJECT_SOURCE_DIR}/HelloOboeEngine)
include_directories(${PROJECT_SOURCE_DIR}/SoundGenerator)

target_include_directories(tunersa PUBLIC
        ${PROJECT_BINARY_DIR}
        ${PROJECT_SOURCE_DIR}/HelloOboeEngine
        ${PROJECT_SOURCE_DIR}/SoundGenerator)
```

This is my HelloOboeEngine/CMakeLists.txt

```
SET(SOURCE_FILES "HelloOboeEngine.cpp")
SET(HEADER_FILES "HelloOboeEngine.h")

add_library(HelloOboeEngine SHARED ${SOURCE_FILES} ${HEADER_FILES})
```

This is my SoundGenerator/CMakeLists.txt

```
SET(SOURCE_FILES "SoundGenerator.cpp")
SET(HEADER_FILES "SoundGenerator.h")

add_library(SoundGenerator SHARED ${SOURCE_FILES} ${HEADER_FILES})
```

Now if I need to call SoundGenerator.h from HelloOboeEngine Subdirectory, how can I tell CMake to include that header file? and viceversa.

If anyone can include a solution with an explanation that'd be helpful.

forehand thanks for taking the time to read.

Comment: `SET(SOURCE_FILES "HelloOboeEngine.h")
SET(HEADER_FILES "HelloOboeEngine.h")` why have same header file for both SOURCE_FILES and HEADER_FILES?

Comment: ***if I need to call SoundGenerator.h from HelloOboeEngine Subdirectory, how can I tell CMake to include that header file*** what are you trying to do? Please make sure your software design is modular and has minimum [coupling](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Coupling_(computer_programming)#:~:text=In%20software%20engineering%2C%20coupling%20is,of%20the%20relationships%20between%20modules.).

Comment: In this case, how can I do it with this structure?

Comment: You need to clearly define your requirements first. What exactly you want to do? What does the two sub-directories contain?